# Matplotlib line chart with count?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line chart of a large data set where I want to set the y to a"count"-value.

This is a mock df :

```
my = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
   [['Apple', 1], 
    ['Kiwi',  2],
    ['Clementine', 3],
    ['Kiwi', 1], 
    ['Banana',  2], 
    ['Clementine', 3],
    ['Apple',  1], 
    ['Kiwi',  2]]), 
                    columns=['fruit', 'cheers'])
```

I would like the plot to use the 'cheers' as the x and then have one line for each 'fruit' and the number of times 'cheers'

EDIT: Line graph might not be the best pursuit, please do advise me then. I would like something like this: 
[image]

In the big data set there would maybe one but not several "zeros", maybe I should've made a bigger mock df.

Comment: Please, provide an example of the result you want to get.

Comment: What should happen to the fruits that appear multiple times in your list?

Comment: @Heike am wondering if scatterplot is a better (more mathematical) approach. But for 'Kiwi' as an example that has 2 cheers two times and 1 cheer on time would go from origio to 1, 1 and then to 2,1 and then to 3,0 as it hasn't any 3 cheers so to speak.

Comment: The figure you posted makes no sense when cmpared to the dataframe. You wrote "and the number of times 'cheers'"... Can you explain how you plot the green line (other lines are also not clear to me) for example in your figure?

Comment: @Sheldore If you see the answers that Heike or onion_man presented you might understand. The green line would be how often the value of 2 cheers respectively  1 cheers for the fruit 'Kiwi'.

Comment: @Mactilda: Hold on. Your dataset has `['Kiwi',  2]`, `['Kiwi', 1]` and `['Kiwi',  2]`. Now please explain how you construct the green line in your hand sketched figure from these. I am just curious to know. Shouldn't you have y=2 at x=2 for the green line because `['Kiwi',  2]` is appearing twice? Just like you have for `['Clementine', 3]` and `['Apple', 1]` which both occur twice?

Comment: @Sheldore Yes it should. But the idea of what I wanted to get came across to others at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will plot a line for each 'fruit' where the `x` coordinate is the number of 'cheers' and the `y` coordinate is the cheers counts per fruit.

First, the dataframe is grouped by fruit to get the list of cheers per fruit. Next, a histogram is computed and plotted for each list of cheers. The max_cheers_count is used in order to ensure the same x coordinates for all plotted lines.

**Note:** see @Heike's answer below for a more pythonic solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# convert 'cheers' column to int
my.cheers = my['cheers'].astype(int)

# computes maximal cheers value, to use later for the histogram
max_cheers_count = my['cheers'].max()

# get cheer counts per fruit
cheer_counts = my.groupby('fruit').apply(lambda x: x['cheers'].values)

# for each fruit compute histogram of cheer counts and plot it
plt.figure()
for row in cheer_counts.iteritems():
    histogram = np.histogram(a=row[1], bins=range(1,max_cheers_count+2))
    plt.plot(histogram[1][:-1], histogram[0], marker='o', label=row[0])
plt.xlabel('cheers')
plt.ylabel('counts')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one question which my expose my ignorance; why is this a histogram? If I see this plot I'd call it a line chart but obviously it's histogram by code.

Comment: A histogram is a representation of the distribution of a given variable. It contains the frequency with which the variable takes a certain value (in your example: how often did variable Clementine had a value of 3). It is true that commonly histograms are plotted as bar plots, but the same information can be plotted as a line as well. In other words, the histogram refers to the content of the plot, while the bars or lines is just the way that content is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I see you already accepted an answer, but an alternative way to do this is something like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Apple', 1],
                            ['Kiwi',  2],
                            ['Clementine', 3],
                            ['Kiwi', 1],
                            ['Banana',  2],
                            ['Clementine', 3],
                            ['Apple',  1],
                            ['Kiwi',  2]]),
                  columns=['fruit', 'cheers'])

my_pivot = my.pivot_table(index = 'cheers', 
                          columns = 'fruit', 
                          fill_value = 0, 
                          aggfunc={'fruit':len})['fruit']
my_pivot.plot.line()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: line plot of pivot table]

Answer (score 1):

```
my.groupby('fruit').sum().plot.barh()
```

[image]

---

Note that your example dataframe appears to have the numbers represented as `string` type, so you might change that to `int` before with

```
my.cheers = my.cheers.astype(int)
```

Afaics this because of your initialization of the dataframe via a 2D-array.
You can avoid this by using the dictionary approach to create a dataframe:

```
my = pd.DataFrame(
{'fruit': ['Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Clementine', 'Kiwi', 'Banana', 'Clementine', 'Apple', 'Kiwi'],
'cheers': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]})
```

Comment: Thanks. This just sums up the cheers though, I'd like to show how many times each amount of cheers occurs for each fruit (the original data set is big). I am pleased that you showed me this way of creating df since it's more like r and I was never comfortable with the way I was taught to do.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure iiuc what you mean by `how many times each amount of cheers occurs for each fruit` - or do you need a histogram plot?

Comment: @Mactilda: This answer is complete in my opinion. This is exactly what you described in the question. Please elaborate more and if possible include a desired hand sketched figure to avoid unnecessary wastage of time in modifications of the original answer due to misunderstandings

Comment: @Sheldore As the question title states I'd like a line graph - that might not be the most ideal then please advise me. I have added a sketched figure.

Comment: Maybe, I hope the sketch explains what I mean. @SpghttCd

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to get **exactly** the figure you posted which starts the curves from 0 is following. The idea is to count the frequency of occurrence of each fruit for different cheers and then make use of dictionaries.

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Define the dataframe here
# my = pd.DataFrame(...)

cheers = np.array(my['cheers'])

for fr in np.unique(my['fruit']):
    freqs = Counter(cheers[np.argwhere(my['fruit']==fr)].flatten()) # Count the frequency
    init_dict = {'0': 0}
    init_dict.update({i: 0 for i in np.unique(cheers)}) # Initialize the dictionary with 0 values
    for k, v in freqs.items():
        init_dict[k] = v # Update the values of cheers
    plt.plot(init_dict.keys(), init_dict.values(), '-o', label=fr) # Plot each fruit line

plt.legend()
plt.yticks(range(4))
plt.show()
```

[image]